# Switch this image text in SQL database to url so I can see it in PowerBI or tableau

Tags: sql, url

I need your help on query so I can switch `ChequeImage` to an url so I can visualize it in tableau how?

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB00430001010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101FFDB00430101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101FFC000110802F403F003012200021101031101FFC4001F0000020202030101010000000000000000030402
```

Comment: Hi - unfortunately your question makes no sense. Please can you provide a much more detailed explanation of what your issue is, what you are trying to achieve, etc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a system that my sales representative when receive a cheque from customer they took a photo of the cheque, and i want to visualize all check on bi tool- Tableau or Power, but in sql the image is not url its like the above text:0xFFD8FF..... how i can have  a query to switch to url?